# OpenCV random forest: Setting a random seed

Tags: opencv, random, random-forest

Since there is randomness involved in the computation of a random forest classifier, it is necessary to define a random seed to get reproducible results. How does one do this for OpenCV `CvRTrees`? I do not see such a parameter in [`CvRTParams`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/random_trees.html#cvrtparams-cvrtparams).

**Update:** The API change of OpenCV 3 [removed](http://answers.opencv.org/question/164451/cvrtparams-undeclared-identifier-randomforest-opencv-c/) `CvRTParams`. However, the title question remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on the opencv version you are using.

- While 2.4.9 seems to [use the global](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/modules/ml/src/rtrees.cpp#L223) `cv::theRNG()` , where you can just set `theRNG().state = something`,
- This [no longer seems to be possible](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/ml/src/rtrees.cpp#L93) in opencv3.0

Comment: The OpenCV issue has been migrated to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4839 and is still open.